# What kind of application do I register for a web application that can run at an arbitrary URL?

Tags: google-oauth

We made a CMS that allows users to connect to Google Analytics via a connector. I'm in the process of porting this connector to OAuth2 and am wondering what kind of application I need to register.

The issue is that the CMS is installed by our clients at arbitrary URL so we don't know the complete set of redirect URLs that I would need to register a Web Server application. Google's OAuth won't let me redirect to an arbitrary URL that I pass in during the authorization request?

Would registering an installed application and then using the `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` special redirect URI be best? Seems like this allows the user copy/paste their authorization code from the browser back into our application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the installed application will allow users to copy and paste and not register. This is appropriate if the clients are end users of your application, and not say, configuring it as a plugin which will then provide web services to the client's users (where such users will then be prompted via the OAuth2 consent dialog). In the latter case you probably want to ask your clients to register their own web site as web application with Google and use a configuration tool for your CMS application to set the client's redirect URLs.

Why the distinction? Because in the first case the consent action is about your relationship with your clients, but in the latter case it expresses trust between your clients and their users. For instance, you don't want your CMS application to be disabled for abuse because one of your clients has misbehaved, as it'd affect all your clients. However, if you intermediated the consent you made it difficult for Google to understand the distinction.

Comment: To be clear, the "client" in this case is the application itself which is being authorized by our end-users. It is used to import some Google Analytics data into our CMS application. I hadn't considered having each of our customers register our application with Google. Honestly, though, that may be more work than it's worth. Because the app is making all the API calls to Google on a schedule we determine, I believe it still makes sense for us to maintain the app under our developer account.

Comment: Also, we've found that other APIs that we use that leverage OAuth2 are not as restrictive about where you redirect the user to after they authorize. For example, with Twitter, we programmatically set a redirect URI in the authorization request based on the URL where our customer is running our application. I'm curious as to why Google does not allow us to do the same thing with redirect URIs.

Comment: Indeed, given your answers, I think it is appropriate for you to request your clients to register and paste the URL into their configuration. The reason we don't allow flexibility for the redirect_uri registration is to guarantee security against token leakage.